# Android MediaPlayer not working on Tablet Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I developed ShoutCastInternet Radio and I'm Successfully Playing on Mobile Device,But the Same Code if i execute on Tablet Device,I'm not able to play the Stream,I had Debugged My Code,The Program flow is Stopping at the below line,It is not able to forward to startMediaPlayer() Method,I had used mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync() aslo

**mMediaPlayer.prepare();**

Here My Code:

```
    /**
     * Initializes a StatefulMediaPlayer for streaming playback of the provided
     * stream url
     * 
     * @param streamUrl
     *            The URL of the stream to play.
     */
    public void initializePlayer(String streamUrl) {
        songurl = streamUrl;

        Log.d("service", "iam in initialize player");

        /*
         * if(mMediaPlayer!=null) { resetMediaPlaer(); }
         */
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
            // mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
            // mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            // mMediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MediaPlayerService", "error setting data source");
            // mMediaPlayer.setState(MPStates.ERROR);
        }
        /*
         * mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
         * mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this); //
         * mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
         * mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
         */
        startMediaPlayer();
    }


    /**
     * Starts the contained StatefulMediaPlayer and foregrounds the service to
     * support persisted background playback.
     */
    public void startMediaPlayer() {
        // mMediaPlayer.stop();
        // mMediaPlayer.release();
        // mMediaPlayer=mMediaPlayer1;
        Log.d("service",
                "iam in start mediaplayer" + mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        // Context context = getApplicationContext();

        /*
         * //set to foreground Notification notification = new
         * Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "MediaPlayerService",
         * System.currentTimeMillis()); Intent notificationIntent = new
         * Intent(this, TORiLTActivity.class);
         * notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         * PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
         * notificationIntent, 0);
         * 
         * CharSequence contentTitle = "MediaPlayerService Is Playing";
         * CharSequence contentText =
         * mMediaPlayer.getStreamStation().getStationLabel();
         * notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
         * pendingIntent); startForeground(1, notification);
         */

        Log.d("MediaPlayerService", "startMediaPlayer() called");
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

**LogCat:**

```
05-16 16:18:02.573: D/connection(6989): connection:true
05-16 16:18:06.839: D/HS1(6989): onCreate
05-16 16:18:06.874: D/HS1(6989): onCreate>>
05-16 16:18:06.905: I/facebook(6989): connection
05-16 16:18:07.136: I/Ads(6989): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD");
05-16 16:18:07.257: I/dalvikvm(6989): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
05-16 16:18:07.339: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - US Pacific
05-16 16:18:07.339: D/dalvikvm(6989): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads35864.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
05-16 16:18:07.460: D/webviewglue(6989): nativeDestroy view: 0x3251e8
05-16 16:18:07.464: D/dalvikvm(6989): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 7044 objects / 606040 bytes in 71ms
05-16 16:18:07.468: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - US Pacific
05-16 16:18:07.472: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - US Eastern
05-16 16:18:07.480: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - UK(GMT)
05-16 16:18:07.483: D/dalvikvm(6989): DexOpt: --- END 'ads35864.jar' (success) ---
05-16 16:18:07.483: D/dalvikvm(6989): DEX prep '/data/data/com.teluguone.torilt/cache/ads35864.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 144ms
05-16 16:18:07.507: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - IST
05-16 16:18:07.523: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Classics - Australia
05-16 16:18:07.526: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Generations - Ghantasala Era
05-16 16:18:07.534: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Generations - Illayaraja - SPB Era
05-16 16:18:07.538: D/lazyadapter(6989): dataTORi Generations - AR Rehman Era
05-16 16:18:07.612: I/Ads(6989): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"10588385027800554711","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a151948104adce5","u_w":400,"msid":"com.teluguone.torilt","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"iSlmx8MDGSoStzndnqerF57udsjToRAUBWellinDkya6sCuwm-4FE6z-4l7o_dKKqljmiesC7Kd3KPZo1p3AgAxZSHBFuZknpTVw320iBWFvWQ2RWHiNTlKL0bBwgHx86av7zoYlxNcN9lIP8VkGjFiDoB_UV_xJ5iqjiEwrzNxJMGyQ1sP-rbn2L8_1emUMJu8ryYCZJqXVB7DNXpKTdIFqIPxnrGprSox8YJYGpz9LG1_TznXnJVjD3X96_KfbEQfYOv5np2E6EJ88UO31T32z-an8A1isa0go4c9W4vMHtiiwr9HPdpaf_VAvOFbADwHyoBk9nJlfOdPAEiv84Q","mv":"8016014.com.android.vending","isu":"CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.teluguone.torilt","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":181,"x":0,"width":900},"gnt":1,"u_h":682,"pt":1,"carrier":"40407","bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
05-16 16:18:07.624: D/MainActivity(6989): service connected
05-16 16:18:07.624: D/if(6989): media null
05-16 16:18:07.624: D/service(6989): iam in initialize player
05-16 16:18:07.624: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6989): native_setup
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer(6989): constructor
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer(6989): setListener
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6989): setAudioStreamType: 3
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer(6989): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6989): setDataSource: path http://38.101.195.5:9156/
05-16 16:18:07.628: V/MediaPlayer(6989): setDataSource(http://38.101.195.5:9156/)
05-16 16:18:07.640: V/MediaPlayer(6989): prepare
```

Updated Logcat:

```
05-17 11:13:22.623: D/dalvikvm(4359): DexOpt: load 1ms, verify 36ms, opt 0ms
05-17 11:13:22.627: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Classics - US Eastern
05-17 11:13:22.631: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Classics - UK(GMT)
05-17 11:13:22.643: D/dalvikvm(4340): DexOpt: --- END 'ads63728.jar' (success) ---
05-17 11:13:22.643: D/dalvikvm(4340): DEX prep '/data/data/com.teluguone.torilt/cache/ads63728.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 127ms
05-17 11:13:22.659: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Classics - IST
05-17 11:13:22.663: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Classics - Australia
05-17 11:13:22.663: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Generations - Ghantasala Era
05-17 11:13:22.678: D/lazyadapter(4340): dataTORi Generations - Illayaraja - SPB Era
05-17 11:13:22.702: D/MainActivity(4340): service connected
05-17 11:13:22.702: D/if(4340): media null
05-17 11:13:22.702: D/service(4340): iam in initialize player
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4340): native_setup
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer(4340): constructor
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer(4340): setListener
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4340): setAudioStreamType: 3
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer(4340): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4340): setDataSource: path http://38.101.195.5:9156/
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/MediaPlayer(4340): setDataSource(http://38.101.195.5:9156/)
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/PVPlayer(2394): PVPlayer constructor
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/PVPlayer(2394): construct PlayerDriver
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/PlayerDriver(2394): constructor
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/PlayerDriver(2394): OpenCore hardware module not found
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/PlayerDriver(2394): start player thread
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/AlarmManager(2487): Checked for alarms... rtc=1368769402705, elapsed=1174139
05-17 11:13:22.702: V/AlarmManager(2487): sending alarm Alarm{482b3d10 type 2 cellfish.spidermanlwp}
05-17 11:13:22.713: V/PlayerDriver(2394): startPlayerThread
05-17 11:13:22.713: V/PlayerDriver(2394): InitializeForThread
05-17 11:13:22.713: V/PlayerDriver(2394): OMX_MasterInit
05-17 11:13:22.733: V/PlayerDriver(2394): OsclScheduler::Init
05-17 11:13:22.733: V/PlayerDriver(2394): CreatePlayer
05-17 11:13:22.772: D/(2394): SISO TEST registering PVMFRecognizerPluginFactory
05-17 11:13:22.780: D/(2394): SISO TEST registering PVMFRecognizerPluginFactory success
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): AddToScheduler
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): PendForExec
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): OsclActiveScheduler::Current
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): StartScheduler
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PVPlayer(2394): send PLAYER_SETUP
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): Send player code: 2
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): CommandCompleted
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): Completed command PLAYER_SETUP status=1
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PVPlayer(2394): setDataSource(http://38.101.195.5:9156/)
05-17 11:13:22.780: I/PlayerDriver(2394): PlayerDriver::isProtectedFile(http://38.101.195.5:9156/)
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): File EXT is : 156/
05-17 11:13:22.780: E/PlayerDriver(2394): PlayerDriver::it is a not Protected file
05-17 11:13:22.780: D/Before Prepare(4340): Before Prepare
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/MediaPlayer(4340): prepare
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PVPlayer(2394): prepareAsync
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PVPlayer(2394):   data source = http://38.101.195.5:9156/
05-17 11:13:22.780: V/PlayerDriver(2394): Send player code: 3
05-17 11:13:22.784: V/PlayerDriver(2394): handleSetDataSource
05-17 11:13:22.784: V/PlayerDriver(2394): handleSetDataSource- scanning for extension
05-17 11:13:22.791: E/(2394): IIIIIII Inside Constructor of PVMFMemoryBufferWriteDataStreamImpl
05-17 11:13:22.795: I/Ads(4340): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"17067838220037024582","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a151948104adce5","u_w":400,"msid":"com.teluguone.torilt","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","ms":"oEgs7AKryna8KvMqjp_veS4HICbxcQXk86Dgp8cc21LM7ksOsDLF36O3QFRPR4Y204YM2NfWWbvnxM8Jr8KEi-j-MXNUqBlyS31OWOOiSo0v1iUYlZsYGhG_EAleiYSLv8oWMvUvTPSP7eVF_uUtssWKhL7YQZHs3YvpAKtrA3wDx_dOOhLSwDZdnnFHjy3zTUK8JQN6K4T-p-7Wpiyyz7Zowa_-vqgkd0_qzFelKxEKVGnq1NszZLUPY2RPJcwlpx47MudnL4n4hRi2DnZRdDQodDsQY2ITW_lLgw4DSaI0cQJNc7WvHT26WUIwUscFot5Nd4tqxf7wxBGN5tAuAw","mv":"8016014.com.android.vending","isu":"CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD","bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.teluguone.torilt","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":181,"x":0,"width":900},"gnt":1,"u_h":682,"pt":1,"carrier":"40407","bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
05-17 11:13:22.799: V/PlayerDriver(2394): CommandCompleted
05-17 11:13:22.799: V/PlayerDriver(2394): Completed command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE status=1
05-17 11:13:22.799: V/PVPlayer(2394): run_init s=0, cancelled=0
05-17 11:13:22.799: V/PlayerDriver(2394): Send player code: 6
05-17 11:13:22.799: V/PlayerDriver(2394): release string is 2.2 len 3
05-17 11:13:25.327: I/AudioHardwareALSA(2394): Output standby called!!. Turn off PCM device.
05-17 11:13:27.945: W/PowerManagerService(2487): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x1
05-17 11:13:27.945: I/PowerManagerService(2487): Ulight 7->3|0
05-17 11:13:32.051: W/ActivityManager(2487): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-17 11:13:32.104: W/ActivityManager(2487): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4836f658 com.teluguone.torilt/.TORiLTActivity}
05-17 11:13:37.151: W/ActivityManager(2487): Activity destroy timeout
```

Could any one help?

Comment: Where is the error portion of your logcat?Your logcat is not much helpful. post the stack trace

Comment: Also tell us which tablet and OS version has problem.

Comment: I'm using andriod FirmvareVersion 2.2 for Tablet

Comment: I had updated my logcat